# how to retrive folders that windows removed using NTUSERS.DAT

Tags: windows-7

I have a Toshiba laptop, using MS Windows 7 on internal hard drive.  Booting an external USB drive (KALI and Ubuntu linux), I created \oracle\honey folder and moved about 100GB of user folders into it.  When I  started Windows later, it removed all data from the honey folder and created several NTUSER.DAT files.
No backup.  How can I retrieve the missing folders?